Is there an alternate default cursor up movement key in Vim normal mode?
In the normal mode of Vim (default keymaps), other than hjkl or the arrow keys, spacebar moves the cursor right, backspace moves the cursor left, enter moves the cursor down. Is there another key (not k or up arrow) that moves the cursor up one line in normal mode?

- can be used to go to the first non-blank character of the previous line.
gk can be used to move the cursor up (differs from k because it moves the cursor directly up one line even with wrap on).
Source / more info:
:help up-down-motions
